# Notify the user when time approaches to zero by changing colour or animation to the timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am using `jQuery Countdown Timer & Digital Clock Plugin` to create a countdown timer as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeTo.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
        < script src = "jquery.timeTo.js" >
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.timeTo.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timeval = 60;
        var timeval = 60;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#countdown').timeTo({
                seconds: timeval,
                displayHours: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to change the **color of the timer to red if the time <5sec mean approaches to zero**. In order to notify the user that time is going to end.

**Also want to redirect to another page once it reached zero.**

Please check the [Link for API](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Digital-Clock-Plugin-timeTo.html)

Please guide me how can make it?

Comment: countdownAlertLimit: 5 ? http://jsfiddle.net/vo0xg1mc/

Comment: you should post it as an answer

Comment: @GL.awog buddy I want to redirect to another page when it reaches zero .Your code workes fine. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `countdownAlertLimit: 5` for your requirement as follow :

```
var timeval = 60;
$('#countdown').timeTo({ seconds: timeval, displayHours: false, countdownAlertLimit: 5 });
```

also note if you want to redirect to another page you can use this line of code :

```
var timeval = 60;
$('#countdown').timeTo({ seconds: timeval, displayHours: false,   countdownAlertLimit: 5,callback:function(){
window.location="your location"
} });
```

When the timer reach 5 the timer will become red.

hope that will help

Comment: need to redirect once it reaches zero as well.

Comment: What I mean is I need red colour when it approaches to zer means <sec. That working fine as per your first code., How can I integrate the first and second line of your code to make it red <5 and also redirect to another page when it reaches 0sec. hope you understand.

Comment: the first line will change the counter to Red when it is `=`or `<` than 5 and the second code will redirect the user to another page when it reach 0

Comment: Tried not working. Can you make a fiddle it will be helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. It's already the way you want it if I understood right!

http://lexxus.github.io/jq-timeTo/